# Make nginx proxy_pass to upstream servers using multiple proxy_ssl_certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, nginx, certificate, client-certificates

I have a use-case where upstream servers will trust different CAs. This is mainly happening during transition period and hence I would like to have my nginx proxy to the upstream servers by trying two different CA certs.

Currently I have an idea of doing something like:

```
location /upstream1 {
  proxy_pass                      https://$http_host$uri;
  proxy_ssl_certificate           /home/keys/cert.pem
  proxy_ssl_certificate_key       /home/keys/key.pem
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate   /home/keys/trust.pem
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  recursive_error_pages on;
  error_page 495 496 = @use_cert2
}

location @use_cert2 {
  proxy_pass                      https://$http_host$uri;
  proxy_ssl_certificate           /home/keys/cert2.pem
  proxy_ssl_certificate_key       /home/keys/key2.pem
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate   /home/keys/trust2.pem
}
```

Is this the most elegant way to have the logic of "try to use this certificate to proxy to upstream server. If the server doesn't like it, then use this different certificate".

Also it calls @use_cert2, does it preserve any rewrite that happened in the previous call block?

Apology in advance if the question does not have enough information.

Thank you for reading the post!